# Change GridViewItem background color when loading

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView with UserControl as item. When I'm scrolling, the UserControl are loading, the background in my UserControl is tranparent, but when its loading, the color of the background is a dark gray.

Is it possible to change the "loading" color of the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty limited information there.

Okay, so your user control could default to a loading color and when it detects the load is complete it changes its own background color to the final color.

Two, you could uses phases to control the rendering order of an item in your list. Making phase 0 your loading color and phase X (whatever is last) your final color. Complex? Yes, but would certainly work.

> You would accomplish it using [IncrementalUpdate](http://www.davidbritch.com/2014/02/using-incrementalupdatebehavior-to.html). More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanxia/archive/2013/11/04/incremental-update-item-data-for-listviewbased-controls-in-windows-8-1.aspx).

Because I don't know more how you might detect that an item is loaded, I can only hope that those first two suggestions will help. I certainly hope they do.

// best of luck

Comment: Yeah, don't think I was clear. My tablet is not very fast, but its doing it also on my pc. I have a GriView with 700 items, the items are not loading instantly, my items are tranparent, but when they are loading, lets say for half a second, the backgroud of the loading items are not transparent, its gray. You can change background of the main Frame of you app so it won't "flash" between navigation, is there a default background color for the GridViewItem I could change, to put transparent?

Comment: Ya thanks, the ShowsScrollingPlaceholders to False did the trick, I already had a way to show a ProgressRing and replace it with my image after, by not showing the placeholders, there is no more dark background.